# Rails Marketplace app - AWS Permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a marketplace app on Rails 4 / Paperclip and am using AWS S3 for image storage. I want the image urls to be https (or else my ssl cert shows warnings on certain browsers)

Based on documentation about [paperclip AWS settings](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3), it says "s3_protocol: The protocol for the URLs generated to your S3 assets. Can be either 'http', 'https', or an empty string to generate protocol-relative URLs. Defaults to 'http' when your :s3_permissions are :public_read (the default), and 'https' when your :s3_permissions are anything else."

Per the above, the different s3_permissions are here under the [canned acl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) section.

My question is for a marketplace where I want multiple users to be able to upload images, should I use the **public-read-write** setting? It doesn't sound too secure - does that mean anyone can edit the image or delete it?

Ideally, I want a permission where only the image owner(a seller) or bucket owner(me) can overwrite the image and "AllUsers" read the image. Which setting should I use? Or should I be doing something else?

My paperclip settings:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  },
    :s3_protocol => :https,
    :s3_permissions => :public_read_write
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the default public_read, all uploads come through the controller (where user is authenticated with devise and pundit) and paperclip uploads to the bucket with the AWS access credentials.

Comment: But for https, I can't use public_read. I need to use one of the others.